# Capturing a Repeated Group with reference

Tags: regex

I tried to find the digits (less the first) with this expression, but it works only with the last digit... I know that need capturing a repeat group and not repeating a captured group but I dont understand how is it.

reg:

```
(\d*)[a-zA-Z]+\d+(?:\.(\d*))*\.[a-zA-Z]+
```

example

```
1212asdfasdfdasf101.102.103.asdsadasdasd

1213asdfasdfdasf104.105.106.asdsadasdasd
```

I want capture 102 and 103, 105, 106, but 1212 and 1213 too. How?? Thanks!

Comment: which language/environment/tool/regex flavor are you using this in? you are still repeating a capturing group (the outer `*` repeats the `(\d*)`). unless you are using .NET, you need a workaround

Comment: I use visual basic 2008, the best opcion that I found was to get .102.103 like a capturing group and more later another group capturing but only with the script ".102.103."
But it is two times using regex, maybe there is a form with only one regex

Comment: so we are talking .NET? in this case, have a look at the `Group` object returned for your second capturing group. it will have a property `Captures` in which you can get all numbers

Comment: Are you sure? The second capturing group only get 103, not 102 and 103 :S

Comment: @user2542437: What do you want your output to be from your example text?  You want every instance of a digit+ in a group, but you want the entire string to be in one match?  More info about how you're using this result may help in finding a solution.

Comment: @user2542437 don't use `Group.Value`, use `Group.Captures(0).Value` and `Group.Captures(1).Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on which language you're using.

For most flavours of regex,there is no "simple" answer... For instance, you might think you could do something like this:

```
^(?:.*?(\d+))+
```

...Which would (you'd hope) create a new capture group for each group of digits.

However, if you have a quick look at (for example) the [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg), then you'll see it says:

> Capturing groups are numbered by counting their opening parentheses from left to right

i.e. There is a *fixed* number, as specified by how many pairs of brackets you typed! Thus, in most languages, you'll need to do more than a simple regex match in order to do this job.

That is, unless you can make your regex less generalised (and much more ugly), by doing something horrible like:

```
^(?:.*?(\d+))?(?:.*?(\d+))?(?:.*?(\d+))?(?:.*?(\d+))?
```

You *can*, however, perform this regex match properly, using [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx) or Perl 6.